# Elisp for expressing directory hierarchy in plain text

Tags: emacs, elisp, hierarchy, directory

On emacs mailing lists I've seen people paste their directory hierarchy like so:

```
|-- .yas-make-groups
|-- collections
|   |-- each
|   `-- ...
|-- control structure
|   |-- forin
|   `-- ...
|-- definitions
|   `-- ...
`-- general
    `-- ...
```

where .yas-make-groups would be a file, and collections would be a directory, etc.

I'm guessing this is a naive question, but is there some elisp code that no one told me about that I can use for this, or some package that does this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `tree` command-line program's the right answer, but if you also use `org-mode` (and you should!), check out [org-fstree](http://burtzlaff.de/org-fstree/).

Comment: Yes, I believe this is what I was looking for.

Comment: And yes, you should use org-mode :)

Answer (score 4):

I don't think this is emacs or lisp, but the `tree` command. Have a look at http://linux.die.net/man/1/tree

The package containing this is also named tree. A visit to Google should find you a package for your favorite OS.

///BR, Jens

Comment: I knew it had to be an outside command...and yet I kept thinking that dired must have an output format like this. Time for a patch!

Comment: And it's [available for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/tree.htm) as a part of gnuwin32!

Answer (score 0):

Untested, quick and dirty. Piggy backs on the shell `tree` command

```
(defun tree (directory) 
  (interactive "D")
  (save-excursion
    (let ((b (get-buffer-create "*tree")))
      (switch-to-buffer b)
      (shell-command (concat "/usr/bin/tree " directory) b))))
```